# JSON TO APEX conversion with number variable name

Tags: apex, json

This is my JSON

```
{
"user":{  
      "self":"https://my.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?username=admin",
      "name":"admin",
      "key":"admin",
      "emailAddress":"test.test@gmail.com",
      "avatarUrls":{  
         "48x48":"https://my.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?ownerId=admin&avatarId=10500",
         "24x24":"https://my.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?size=small&ownerId=admin&avatarId=10500",
         "16x16":"https://my.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?size=xsmall&ownerId=admin&avatarId=10500",
         "32x32":"https://my.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?size=medium&ownerId=admin&avatarId=10500"
      },
      "displayName":"Ratan[Administrator]",
      "active":true,
      "timeZone":"Asia/Kolkata"
   }
}
```

My fav site for converting into Apex https://www.adminbooster.com/tool/json2apex

Generated apex class.

```
public class fromJSON{
    public cls_user user;
    class cls_user {
        public String self; 
        public String name; 
        public String key;  
        public String emailAddress; 
        public cls_avatarUrls avatarUrls;
        public String displayName;  
        public boolean active;
        public String timeZone;
    }
    class cls_avatarUrls {
        public String 48x48; // profile picture size    
        public String 24x24;    
        public String 16x16;    
        public String 32x32;    
    }
    public static fromJSON parse(String json){
        return (fromJSON) System.JSON.deserialize(json, fromJSON.class);
    }
}
```

Now my problem is below

```
class cls_avatarUrls {
            public String 48x48; // profile picture size    
            public String 24x24;    
            public String 16x16;    
            public String 32x32;    
        }
```

If I try to save then receives **unexpected token: '48'**

I know we can't use integer **48x48** here.

So is there way to solve this issue/problem

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve your problem you can declare avatarUrls as a Map.

**Code Example**

```
public class fromJSON{
    public cls_user user;
    class cls_user {
        public String self; 
        public String name; 
        public String key;  
        public String emailAddress; 
        public Map<String,String> avatarUrls;
        public String displayName;  
        public boolean active;
        public String timeZone;
    }

    public static fromJSON parse(String json){
        return (fromJSON) System.JSON.deserialize(json, fromJSON.class);
    }
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use JSON.deserializedUntyped to generate a map. Unlike concrete classes, maps can hold settings that start with numbers.

Comment: Yes I can use `JSON.deserializedUntyped` but I don't want to use reason my JSON data is nearly 500 line of code. So its better to use Apex class.

Comment: @Ratan Trust me, you'll find that the only other solutions are *at least* as difficult to use. You want to deserialize into a generic map.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. I will remember your solution for future use.

Answer (score 1):

In Salesforce, you cannot have variables starting with a number. While you can add an underscore to the beginning of the variable, your automatic JSON parsing will fail to assign values to those variables

If possible, the ideal is to modify the original JSON. If not, you can use a "Search & Replace" (you can use string methods within SFDC) to manipulate the received JSON so those variable names match the classes.

Unless you have a huge JSON payload (which may blow your heap) you should be fine.