# JSON: how to declare an attribute whose name contains $ symbol?

Tags: apex, json, variable-names

I have written apex class.variable declaration is:

```
public string QPA$MV2 {get;set;}
```

It shows error:

> Error: Compile Error: Invalid identifier: QPA$MV2 at line 254 column
>   23 How to resolve it ?

Comment: you can't use special character as variable name.. why you are using $ ?

Comment: I have generated apex class from JSON.In that structure there is a $ variable

Comment: instead string take a `map<String,String>` this will solve your issue .. check this post I had same issue before http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100667/json-to-apex-conversion-with-number-variable-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `class`/`property`/`method` identifiers must be alphanumeric and cannot contain the underscore (`_`) character twice in a row. At least for [class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_classes.htm), you can find a good description of the rules:

> The name can only contain characters, letters, and the underscore (_) character, must start with a letter, and cannot end with an underscore or contain two consecutive underscore characters.

I think by `characters, letters, and the underscore (_) character`, they meant *`numbers`*`, letters, and the underscore (_) character`.

Your original post made no mention of JSON, but you can find solutions to that problem [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/how-do-you-deserialize-json-properties-that-are-reserved-words-in-apex).

Comment: if the name contain $ symbol,then what will be the case ?

Comment: @uma It makes the identifier invalid. Use only numbers, letters, and underscores./

Comment: I have generated a class from JSon.Usion JSON to Apex converter I generated the class.it gives the variable as "public double QPA$MV2 {get;set;}"  while saving it shows error.

Comment: @uma - See the link Adrian included. Apex names cannot have $. If the Json2Apex generator gave you invalid variable names, change them to valid ones and use the techniques in the link to fix up the json before you deserialize